# convert std::string to basic_ostream?

Tags: c++

Is there a conversion for the above?

Comment: What end result are you trying to get? Can you clarify a bit more?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Convert a `std::string` to an *output* stream? Usually it's: convert a string to an *input* stream that reads characters from the given string:

```
std::string myString = //...
std::istringstream iss(myString);
```

See also: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istringstream/

Answer (score 6):

`std::ostringstream` from <sstream>:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ostringstream/